# Error with @synthesize'd property

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have two classes, GameCharacter and Skeleton. One of the properties on GameCharacter is a delegate of type id:

```
@interface GameCharacter : GameObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<GameplayLayerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

In the implementation, I have delegate synthesized.

The Skeleton class is pretty straightforward:

```
#import "GameCharacter.h"

@interface Skeleton : GameCharacter
@end
```

However, I am unable use delegate in Skeleton without declaring it separately. I receive an error from the compiler. As I understand it, it should inherit it from GameCharacter. What's the problem?

Comment: It will inherit from `GameCharacter` just like any other property or method. Make sure you are using `self.delegate`

Comment: Ah, I was trying to just use 'delegate' which works fine in the same class because of the synthesized getter.

Comment: Btw are you sure you want to retain the delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will inherit from `GameCharacter` just like any other property or method just make sure you are using `self.delegate` since using `delegate` by itself will attempt to access a private ivar (which would be generated in your case).